# How can I create a capitalized Postgres role name?

Tags: postgresql

I am getting the following error when I try to start my Rails app running a Postgres database:

`ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
FATAL: role "Divergent" does not exist`

To fix this I ran `CREATE ROLE Divergent` from inside the psql console but it only creates a lowercase `divergent`.

How then do I create a role name that matches the case of the name that the Postgres db expects me to have (i.e Divergent with a 'D')? Why does the Postgres db expect me to have this name and can I change it?

Comment: See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS but in general you should avoid quoted identifiers completely. You should check if you can convince your obfuscation layer (aka ORM) to use un-quoted identifiers.

Comment: Still getting the error `FATAL: role 'Divergent' does not exist`. What effect will creating a db have on the role name?

Comment: I never said you should create a database. You should tell activerecord to **not** quote the role name. The link I provided explains the difference between unquoted and quoted identifiers in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the user name to have it be case sensitive. Note that you'll need to quote it again whenever you use it inside psql (like `GRANT ALL ON table TO "Divergent"`).

You can also use the `createuser` command outside of psql, which is case sensitive: `createuser Divergent`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `config/database.yml`. The username in my development database config was commented out and so postgres was defaulting to using my system username as the default role name. I simply uncommented the line and named it what I wanted. And then in the postgres console I created a role that corresponded to that username. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To create a specific name, you need to use double quotes.
For example to create a role:

```
CREATE ROLE "Divergent";
```